# Проблема с меню в Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Когда контента мало, то все нормально, но вот когда его будет много, больше чем высота меню, то под меню будет свободное место, которое не будет заполняться.

Меню с классом `.col-md-3`, а контент `.col-md-9`, что можно сделать?

[image: пример]

Comment: покажите свой код?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Lm3tXUKu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А прописывать в зависимости от высоты класс col-md-9 || col-md-12 ?

Comment: Извините, но я вас не понял

Comment: Вычислять высоту прокрученной области window.pageYOffset . И если  высота выше чем например 800px(учтем шапку с меню) то прятать меню, а контенту addClass('col-md-12')